# SQL Server query for left join of two table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one is `Table_Log` for when user will update the data then it will stored one data into `Table_Log`, and another table is main registration table: `Table_Registration` and I need based on `updatedDate` of `Table_Log` data should come first order by desc.

Table_Log:

```
RegId   Name  updatedDate
-----------------------------------
 3      jj    2018-03-21 13:30:04.497
 3      jj    2018-03-20 13:30:04.497
```

Table_Registration

```
RegId   Name   Email             SubDate
--------------------------------------------------------
 2      kk     kk@gmail.com      2018-03-01 15:30:04.497
 3      jj     jj@gmail.com      2018-02-26 15:30:04.497
 1      Raj    raj@gmail.com     2018-02-30 13:30:04.497
```

I need this output as my result:

```
RegId   Name   Email             SubDate
--------------------------------------------------------
 3      jj     jj@gmail.com      2018-02-26 15:30:04.497
 2      kk     kk@gmail.com      2018-03-01 15:30:04.497
 1      Raj    raj@gmail.com     2018-02-30 13:30:04.497
```

I tried below query but some duplication is coming.

```
select r.*
from Table_Registration r
left join Table_Log a 
 on a.RegId = r.RegId  
order by isnull(a.updatedDate, r.SubDate) desc
```

Comment: So...What's your question?

Comment: I need output result that is my question. @D-Shih

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: I need data order by updatedDate from Table_log. @dotnetstep

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Try writing the code then come here to ask specific questions about specific problems that you are having with the code that you write

Comment: Dear I updated my question what i tried and hope now you will give some suggestion and answer. @HeedfulCrayon

Comment: Ya you are correct updateddate used for only for sorting, no i do not want to see data of Log Table, its just for sorting purpose. @DancingFool

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.*
from Table_Registration r
left join Table_Log a 
  on a.RegId = r.RegId  
order by isnull(a.updatedDate, r.SubDate) desc
```

In the above code, you left join to Table Log. This will give you one row per row of tablelog, which is why you are getting duplication. You need to process table_Log in some way so that you are only getting the most recent row per registration, and then join to that. Something like this

```
select r.*
from Table_Registration r
left join (Select RegId, Max(updateDate) as updateDate from Table_Log Group By RegId) a
  on a.RegId = r.RegId 
order by isnull(a.updatedDate, r.SubDate) desc
```

Comment: Ya you are correct updateddate used for only for sorting, no i do not want to see data of Log Table, its updateddate  just for sorting purpose. @DancingFoo

Comment: isnull(a.updatedDate, r.SubDate) this parting is not working its accepting only(a.RegId, r.SubDate) not accepting a.updatedDate. @DancingFool

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the solution above. I forgot to name the Max(updateDate) column in the subquery - it loses its automatic name from the column when you put the max() around it.